# Using mysql_config_editor within shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I am having trouble understanding *why* this line works in command line:

```
mysql --login-path=local
```

I get teh typical `mysql> _` prompt as expected.

However when I use the following in my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --login-path=local -e "SELECT contractor FROM contractor" | while read contractor; do
    echo "Contractor: $contractor"
done
```

This is what happens when I try to run that small script:

> **zak@yserver:$** sh contractors.sh
>       ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zak'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

The problem is, when I set up `local` I used the `root` user (I know bad idea -- but this is just a proof of concept not production) like so:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
```

From what I have read, I am using this correctly -- And it works on command line .. Just not in my shell script -- Is there a problem with my syntax?

After much thought -- I am having trouble understanding why 1) it's using the `zak` username -- And 2) it's using PASSWORD `NO` - When I clearly set the username as `root` and entered a password on the prompt.

**update**

it also fails if I use `bash` instead of `sh` --  IE

> > **zak@yserver:$** bash contractors.sh
> >         ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zak'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Are you running the script from the same user that runs the interactive `mysql`? It looks in the current user's `.mylogin.cnf` file.

Comment: I am using the same user --  `zak@`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it works for you on the command line, but the `mysql_config_editor` credentials are stored in the system user's `home` directory.

So if you run:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
```

...as user `zak`, then the `.mylogin.cnf` credentials file will be stored in `/home/zak/` and should have permissions set to allow only `zak` to access it.

If you don't pass any username or password to `mysql`, then it uses your system `user`, which explains your error message (`Access denied for user 'zak'@'localhost').

If you set the credentials as `root`, then they will be saved in `/root`. You can copy them to `/home/zak/`, change permissions to `600` and ownership to `zak:zak` and then they should work for your user as well.

Or you can just run the `mysql_config_editor` command as `zak`.